# Insert Image automatically when upload finishes wordpress media uploader

Tags: uploads, media

What I am trying to do is -

1) User clicks "Add Media"

2) Select an image

3) Image uploads finishes

4) Now it should insert into post automatically without pressing "Insert into post".

Anywhere to hook, and click the "Insert into post" using jquery.

Any clues ?

Comment: The code for the media library is not fun to work with - trust me.

Comment: you're right, I am looking for any hack though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hook for doing stuff after an upload is the `reset` event on `wp.Uploader.queue` triggered by the pluploader when it's finished (see line 249 in "wp-includes/js/plupload/wp-plupload.js"). Here's one hack to use this to do an auto-insert after an upload:

```
function wpse167143_admin_footer() {
?>
<script>
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    typeof wp.Uploader !== 'undefined' && wp.Uploader.queue.on( 'reset', function () {
        // From the primary toolbar (".media-toolbar-primary")
        // get the insert button view (".media-button-insert")
        // and execute its click (as specified in its options).
        wp.media.frame.toolbar.get('primary').get('insert').options.click();
    } );
});
</script>
<?php
}
add_action( 'admin_footer' , 'wpse167143_admin_footer' );
```